# Flutter - ERROR : HTTP 405 Method not allowed

Tags: json, api, http, flutter, dart

I'm trying to read json file through an API that was given to me by a client, but It's giving HTTP error 405 saying method not allowed. Can anyone please tell what I'm doing wrong?

This api request snippet was given to me :

```
curl 'http://finelistings.com/backend/apis/webbrands/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' --data-binary '{}' --compressed --insecure
```

```dart
Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("http://finelistings.com/backend/apis/webbrands/"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
      }
    );

    Map<String, String> data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print(data);
  }
```

Comment: is the Curl call working correctly?

Comment: There's a [great resource](https://curl.trillworks.com/#dart) that converts curl commands to dart. As @Torkel noticed, you need to submit as a POST. You missed the part of the curl command that says `--data-binary...` which *sends* a body to the server with the request, which has to be done with a POST.

Answer (score 6):

Method not allowed might refer to wrong request method.

Try using POST instead of GET, at least I got a response from that using the mentioned URL.

```
Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.encodeFull("http://finelistings.com/backend/apis/webbrands/"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
      }
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print(data);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this method but now I'm getting a new error on the line `Map<String, String> data = jsonDecode(response.body);`.

**Error:**  `Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>')`

Comment: Try using dynamic instead of string? It's what the error message says